# Random letter swap soloution

Tags: encryption, randomness

I am working on a way to decipher some text generated by a small piece of code (see below).

This piece of code swaps letters in the sentence at random and was wondering if there where any techniques to solve this? I have tried frequency analysis, however because it is not a simple substitution cipher this does not work.

Here is the text:

```
NBWHJO MIIOI CAMC JSERIXSMBO FMQ QOOWHT M QWKMZSO WHJBOMQO WH OBBEBQ WH CBMXXWJ XEB WCQ JRQCEPOBQ ZOJMRQO CAO MCCMJV FMQ MXXOJCWHT WHXBMQCBRJCRBO NBEGWIOBQ SWVO TWCARZ. "WX M JRQCEPOB'Q QWCO WQ NEWHCWHT CE M TWC CAOBO, HEF FO JMH'C BOMJA TWCARZ," AO QMWI. "CAOBO MBO IOXWHWCOSY WHXBMQCBRJCRBO NBEGWIOBQ CAMC FO JMH'C BOMJA.
```

Here is the code (Python)

```
import random

def shuffle(string):
    string = list(string)
    for i in range(0, len(string)):
        # Choose two random letters in the string
        index_one = random.randint(0, len(string)-1)
        index_two = random.randint(0, len(string)-1)

        # Swap letters        
        buffer = string[index_one]
        string[index_one] = string[index_two]
        string[index_two] = buffer
    return ''.join(string)
```

Comment: Unless you know the RNG seed, there's no way to reverse that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple transposition cipher—effectively, a very long anagram. It might be possible to exploit the nonuniform distribution on the permutation of positions—a standard Knuth shuffle works a little differently to give all permutations of positions equal probability—but probably standard anagram algorithms can enumerate possible solutions that are sequences of (*e.g.*) valid English words to find candidate plaintexts.